# In OpenGL one line disappears after drawing another

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL, I am trying to implement Bresenham's Line algorithm.

At first, I am drawing two-axis lines. Then the given line would be drawn. But the **horizontal axis is being disappeared after finishing the drawing**.

I am drawing the axis like the following:

```
for (int i = -300; i<=300; i++)
    setPixel(0,i),setPixel(i,0);
```

Have a look on my full code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of Bresenham's Algorithm
 *
 * Written by Enamul Hassan July 2015
 *
 * This program draws a line having two pixel co-ordinate
 * using Bresenham's line Algorithm.
 *
 */
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

/* Program entry point */
double x1, y1, x2, y2;


/**
 * setPixel(int,int) - This function mainly sets the pixel at the
 *                     co-ordinate (x,y) on the OpenGL screen.
 */
void setPixel(int x, int y)
{   /**
     * glBegin(GLbitfield mask) - delimit the vertices of a primitive or
     *                            a group of like primitives
     *
     * GL_POINTS - Treats each vertex as a single point.
     *             Vertex n defines point n. N points are drawn.
     */
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    /**
     * glVertex2f(float,float) - This function takes two floating
     *                           point values of co-ordinate and
     *                           set the point.
     */
    glVertex2f(x,y);

    /**
     * Sleep(int) - wait time in milliseconds. It is for distinguish
     *              two operations.
     */
//    Sleep(5);

    /**
     * glEnd() - end of the environment created by glBegin(int)
     */
    glEnd();

    /**
     * glutSwapBuffers() -  swaps the buffers of the current window
     *                      if double buffered
     */
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void bresenham_algo(void)
{
    /**
     * glClear(GLbitfield mask) — clear buffers to preset values
     * GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT - Indicates the buffers currently
     *                       enabled for color writing
     * GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT - Indicates the depth buffer
     */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    /**
     * void glColor3d(GLdouble red, GLdouble green, GLdouble blue) -
     *          set RGB color.
     */
    glColor3d(1,0,0); // cyan color
    for (int i = -350; i<=350; i++)
        setPixel(0,i),setPixel(i,0);

    glColor3d(0,1,1); // cyan color

    ///Main algorithm

    int x1prime = x1+0.5;
    int x2prime = x2+0.5;
    int y1prime = y1+0.5;
    int y2prime = y2+0.5;

    double m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);

    if(!(0<=m && m<=1))
    {
        printf("m should be in range of 0 to 1.\n");
        printf("To get the mirrored counter part, swap the co-ordinates accordingly.\n");
        exit(0);
        return;
    }


    int x = x1prime, y = y1prime;
    int dx = x2prime - x1prime, dy = y2prime - y1prime, dT = 2*(dy-dx), dS = 2*dy;
    int d = 2*dy - dx;
    setPixel(x,y);

    while(x<x2prime)
    {
        x++;
        if(d<0) d+=dS;
        else y++,d+=dT;
        setPixel(x,y);
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /**
     * glutInit(int, char*) - initializes glut environment.
     */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    /**
     * glutInitWindowSize(int,int)- initializes new glut window of
     *                              size W * H
     *                              default: 300, 300
     */
    glutInitWindowSize(700,700);
    /**
     * glutInitWindowPosition(int,int) - set the origin of the
     *                                   co-ordinate
     *                                   default: -1, -1
     */
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);

    /**
     * glutInitDisplayMode(unsigned int) - set the initial display mode.
     *                      It can take a combinations of some masks
     *                      which are not overlapped in their binary
     *                      representation. So, it takes them having
     *                      bitwise OR.
     * GLUT_RGB - the color input would by set by RGB values.
     * GLUT_DOUBLE - makes it double buffered. It is like using two blackboard.
     *               One blackboard would be shown to the screen and hidden one
     *               would be processed behind. they can be swapped any time.
     * GLUT_DEPTH - It is mainly enables depth concept. Algorithm like z-buffering
     *              could be done by using this.
     */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    /**
     * glutCreateWindow(char*) - creates a top-level window having the title
     *                           given as parameter.
     */
    glutCreateWindow("Brasenham's Algorithm for Line Drawing");

    /**
     * gluOrtho2D(GLdouble left, GLdouble right, GLdouble bottom, GLdouble top) -
     *                              define a 2D orthographic projection matrix
     */
    gluOrtho2D(-350,350,-350,350);
    printf("Give the input as: \"x1 y1 x2 y2\" - ");

    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
    if(x1>x2) swap(x1,x2), swap(y1,y2);

    /**
     * void glutDisplayFunc(void (*func)(void))  - this function takes a function pointer
     *                                             in which all works done.
     */
    glutDisplayFunc(bresenham_algo);

    /**
     * glutMainLoop() - enters the GLUT event processing loop. This routine should be
     *                  called at most once in a GLUT program. Once called, this routine
     *                  will never return. It will call as necessary any callbacks that
     *                  have been registered.
     */
    glutMainLoop();


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you are calling `glutSwapBuffers` in your `setPixel` function.

Swapping the buffers means that the current "back" buffer, which is the one you usually drawing into, will become the "front" buffer, which is the one which is displayed by the user. In the old days, this also meant the front buffer becomes the back buffer, hence the term "swapping". However, in modern times, the GL implementation might use several more buffers, are allocate new ones as it sees fit. Technically, *the contents of the back buffer become undefined after you call `SwapBuffers()`*.

So what you have to do is:

Draw the complete image which you want to present too the user, and then, do the buffer swap once. And then, draw a completely new frame from scratch. You can't just repeatedly draw a single pixel, sleep, and swap, and assume that this results in the animation of a line being rendered. You have to re-write your application loop in a way that at ech step of the animation, a complete frame is being rendered.